# How to parse a JSON string into JsonNode in Jackson?

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson

It should be so simple, but I just cannot find it after being trying for an hour.

I need to get a JSON string, for example, `{"k1":v1,"k2":v2}`, parsed as a `JsonNode`.

```
JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
JsonParser jp = factory.createJsonParser("{\"k1\":\"v1\"}");
JsonNode actualObj = jp.readValueAsTree();
```

gives

> `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ObjectCodec defined for the parser, can not deserialize JSON into JsonNode tree`

Comment: `#embarrasing` -- nope. If simple things aren't simple, then the API designer has failed, not you.

Comment: @StaxMan's answer in code: JsonFactory factory = new MappingJsonFactory();

Answer (score 427, accepted):

A slight variation on Richards answer but `readTree` can take a string so you can simplify it to:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode actualObj = mapper.readTree("{\"k1\":\"v1\"}");
```

Comment: For anyone who needs an `ObjectNode` rather than a `JsonNode` use `mapper.valueToTree("{\"k1\":\"v1\"}")`

Comment: @MatthewHerbst In 2.5.1, this creates a new text node with the string "{\"k1\":\"v1\"}" rather than parsing it as JSON.

Answer (score 73):

You need to use an `ObjectMapper`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonFactory factory = mapper.getJsonFactory(); // since 2.1 use mapper.getFactory() instead
JsonParser jp = factory.createJsonParser("{\"k1\":\"v1\"}");
JsonNode actualObj = mapper.readTree(jp);
```

Further documentation about creating parsers can be found [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonStreamingApi#creating-parsers).

Comment: Is it possible to take the JsonNode, modify it a bit, and then call mapper.readValue(node, class);  and get out a class?

Comment: Yes. There's even an alias for that, `mapper.treeToValue()`. But `readValue()` also works.

Answer (score 33):

A third variant:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode actualObj = mapper.readValue("{\"k1\":\"v1\"}", JsonNode.class);
```

Comment: What did passing in JsonNode.class actually get you here?

Comment: @David: Nothing, so slashnick's variant is obviously better if you just want a `JsonNode`. However, you usually don't want a `JsonNode`, so I wanted to show how to tell Jackson what kind of value of you want.

Comment: For me, passing `JsonNode` was apparently necessary to prevent Jackson from deserializing it as something else - which would have failed.

Answer (score 5):

Richard's answer is correct. Alternatively you can also create a `MappingJsonFactory` (in `org.codehaus.jackson.map`) which knows where to find `ObjectMapper`. The error you got was because the regular `JsonFactory` (from `core` package) has no dependency to `ObjectMapper` (which is in the `mapper` package).

But usually you just use `ObjectMapper` and do not worry about `JsonParser` or other low level components -- they will just be needed if you want to data-bind parts of stream, or do low-level handling.

Answer (score 5):

```
import com.github.fge.jackson.JsonLoader;
JsonLoader.fromString("{\"k1\":\"v1\"}")
== JsonNode = {"k1":"v1"}
```

Answer (score 4):

New approach to old question.
A solution that works from java 9+

```
ObjectNode agencyNode = new ObjectMapper().valueToTree(Map.of("key", "value"));
```

is more readable and maintainable for complex objects. Ej

```
Map<String, Object> agencyMap = Map.of(
        "name", "Agencia Prueba",
        "phone1", "1198788373",
        "address", "Larrea 45 e/ calligaris y paris",
        "number", 267,
        "enable", true,
        "location", Map.of("id", 54),
        "responsible", Set.of(Map.of("id", 405)),
        "sellers", List.of(Map.of("id", 605))
);
ObjectNode agencyNode = new ObjectMapper().valueToTree(agencyMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin:

```kt
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.readValue

val data = ObjectMapper().readValue<JsonNode>("{\"field\":\"value\"}")
```