# How to output json string with all qutation mark escaped?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I would like to output json as a string with double quotes surrounding it and all double quotes inside the string escaped. Does Jackson Json provide any function to do it? What I want to do is exactly opposite of [How to parse a JSON string into JsonNode in Jackson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653996/how-to-parse-a-json-string-into-jsonnode-in-jackson).

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I think doing that would make your output a string (formatted like JSON), as opposed to valid JSON.

I tested it with [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/), worth having a go yourself just in case I'm being a dunce.