# how to parse a JSON string into ObjectNode in Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

First of all could anyone explain to me What are differences between ObjectNode and JsonNode, and where they used?

Then if I want to convert a JSON string into ObjectNode what can I do?

Comment: Have you started by reading any documentation, any javadoc?

Comment: No , where can I read about?

Comment: http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to parse a JSON string into JsonNode in Jackson?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653996/how-to-parse-a-json-string-into-jsonnode-in-jackson)

Comment: I read that before but method mapper.readTree() return JsonNode not ObjectNode and I couldn't get ObjectNode from mapper.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode actualObj = mapper.valueToTree("{\"k1\":\"v1\"}")
```

JsonNode it is a super class of ObjectNode.

You can find the differences in the API.

Comment: getJsonFactory() and createJsonParser() is deprecated. Can I do this without deprecated functions?

Comment: I found the answer, I write it in this way and then cast JsonNode to ObjectNode:   `ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  JsonNode actualObj = mapper.readTree(jsonString);`