# how can i parsing this Json String in Java

Tags: java, jackson

my JSON String :

> { 
>     "categorySetName": "TSN",
>     "rows": [
>      {
>         "date": 201750,
>         "rank1": {
>           "label": "\uBC30\uACBD",
>           "search_keyword": "\uBC30\uACBD",
>           "frequency": 3975,
>           "score": 69.27185
>         },
>         "rank2": {
>           "label": "\uBC30\uACBD\uD654\uBA74",
>           "search_keyword": "\uBC30\uACBD\uD654\uBA74",
>           "frequency": 3736,
>           "score": 109.83768
>         },
>         "rank3": {
>           "label": "\uC544\uC774\uD3F0x",
>           "search_keyword": "\uC544\uC774\uD3F0x",
>           "frequency": 3382,
>           "score": 62.057728
>         },
>         .
>         .
>         .
>         .
>         "rank500": {
>           "label": "\uC544\uC774\uD3F0x",
>           "search_keyword": "\uC544\uC774\uD3F0x",
>           "frequency": 1572,
>           "score": 68.057728
>         }
>      }
>   }

my Deserializer.Java

---

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AssociationTopRowDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<AssociationTopRow> {

    public static final String DATE = "date";
    public static final List<String> knownFieldNames = Arrays.asList(DATE);

    public AssociationTopRowDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public AssociationTopRowDeserializer(Class<AssociationTopRow> c) {
        super(c);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public AssociationTopRow deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext desContext) throws IOException {
        AssociationTopRow row = new AssociationTopRow();
        JsonNode jsonNode = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        row.setDate(jsonNode.get(DATE).asText());

        String unknownField = getUnknownField(jsonNode.fieldNames());
        if (unknownField != null) {
            Map<String, AssociationTopRowDetail> map = new HashMap<String, AssociationTopRowDetail>();
            map.put(unknownField, (AssociationTopRowDetail) objectMapper.convertValue(jsonNode.get(unknownField),
                    AssociationTopRowDetail.class));
            row.setTransMap(map);
        }
        return row;
    }

    public String getUnknownField(Iterator<String> fieldNames) {
        while (fieldNames.hasNext()) {
            String next = fieldNames.next();
            if (!knownFieldNames.contains(next))
                return next;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

This shows me only information about only 'rank1'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse a JSON string into JsonNode in Jackson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653996/how-to-parse-a-json-string-into-jsonnode-in-jackson)

Comment: what's the need for using a custom `JsonDeserializer`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@JsonAnySetter` annotation instead of a custom deserializer:

```
public class AssociationTopRow {

    private String date;
    private final Map<String, AssociationTopRowDetail> details = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    // getter & setter for date

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void addDetail(String key, AssociationTopRowDetail detail) {
        details.put(key, detail);
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, AssociationTopRowDetail> getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

}
```